# multiInject in Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, inversifyjs

In Inversify.js there is `multiInject` decorator that allow us to inject multiple objects as array. All objects' dependencies in this array resolved as well.

Is there any way to achieve this in Nest.js?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to `multiInject`. You can provide an array with a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) though:

## Example

Try the example live in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5m2vn8oz5p?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.module.ts).

#### Injectables

Let's assume you have multiple `@Injectable` classes that implement the interface `Animal`.

```
export interface Animal {
  makeSound(): string;
}

@Injectable()
export class Cat implements Animal {
  makeSound(): string {
    return 'Meow!';
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Dog implements Animal {
  makeSound(): string {
    return 'Woof!';
  }
}
```

#### Module

The classes `Cat` and `Dog` are both available in your module (provided there or imported from another module). Now you create a custom token for the array of `Animal`:

```
providers: [
    Cat,
    Dog,
    {
      provide: 'MyAnimals',
      useFactory: (cat, dog) => [cat, dog],
      inject: [Cat, Dog],
    },
  ],
```

#### Controller

You can then inject and use the `Animal` array in a Controller like this:

```
constructor(@Inject('MyAnimals') private animals: Animal[]) {
  }

@Get()
async get() {
  return this.animals.map(a => a.makeSound()).join(' and ');
}
```

---

This also works if `Dog` has additional dependencies like `Toy`, as long as `Toy` is available in the module (imported/provided):

```
@Injectable()
export class Dog implements Animal {
  constructor(private toy: Toy) {
  }
  makeSound(): string {
    this.toy.play();
    return 'Woof!';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor tweak to the great solution by @kim-kern you can use that solution but avoid a small bit of overhead for adding new entries ...

replace

```
providers: [
    Cat,
    Dog,
    {
      provide: 'MyAnimals',
      useFactory: (cat, dog) => [cat, dog],
      inject: [Cat, Dog],
    },
  ],
```

with

```
providers: [
    Cat,
    Dog,
    {
      provide: 'MyAnimals',
      useFactory: (...animals: Animal[]) => animals,
      inject: [Cat, Dog],
    },
  ],
```

It's only minor but instead of having to add a new one in **3** places for every new addition it's down to **2**. Adds up when you have a few and reduces chance of error.

Also the nest team are working on making this easier an you can track via this github issue: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/770